# How to change LinkedIn share image in HTML?

Tags: html, linkedin-api, linkedin-plugins

I developed some html pages with social sharing functionalities like Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn etc.
But now, I have some problem to change LinkedIn image.

To share on LinkedIn I use platform.linkedin.com/in.js plugin:
When I change image from image6.jpg to another JPG file in `metatag og:image`, changed image couldn't be shared.
Please help me to solve this.
Thank you.

Comment: You can change it using jQuery. If you can provide html code returned from plugin, then I can show you how you can achieve this.

Comment: You can see my codes below

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta property="og:description" content="This is my sample for image upload"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="This is my 1st sample"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://socrolife.com/assets/images/image6.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article">
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/Share" ></script>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

I post this answer for the developers touch Linkedin first.

The other social sites have no problem like this.

But facebook and Linkedin have this problem, because these sites have cache and save the first scraping data in cache (especially images).
Facebook cache can be removed by manually, but Linkedin cache can not be.
Linkedin cache restore scraping data for a week, and Linkedin clean cache after a week.

During this period (one week) the page you want to change image wouldn't be shared.
Because as I write, Linkedin show old data in cache , and save it again, so you have to wait for a week.

Only way to change image immediately is to change page url also.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's think about this.  Here is your what I think is the kernel of your problem:

> ...When I change image from image6.jpg to another JPG file in metatag og:image, changed image couldn't be shared....

At first, when you said *When I change image*, I thought you meant changing it in the HTML, but now I think what you mean is you are changing it through JavaScript: i.e. `$(metaelement).content(newimage);`.

If this is what you mean, *it will not work*.  LinkedIn is doing a blind, simple, non-JS activated scrape/parse/cURL of your webpage.  If you try to change `<title>` or `<meta>` tags with JS, the scrape *will not see it.*  This is true with almost every type of scraped URL, in every single search engine, for instance, like google and bing (changing your `<title>` via JS *will not* be reflected in the search result).  *This is just how the Internet currently works!*

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

For example, this works for me:

> https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http://www.wikipedia.org/

See, it works fine:

[image]

If you are interested in a regularly maintained GitHub project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check it out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]